# XeLaTeX size of Indic script in header

Tags: xetex, header-footer, fontsize, fancyhdr, indic

I am using XeLaTeX (TeX Live 2012 on Windows) and my Sanskrit document is entirely in Devanagari. Even the page numbers, section numbers and section names are in Devanagari. I use `fancyhdr` but quite strangely, the size of the output of `lhead` and `rhead` is different. While `lhead`'s text is small, that of `rhead` is large except for the subsection numbers. How can I control the size of the `rhead` to make it the same as `lhead`? Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS} 
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
   \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{अमुकग्रन्थे}} 
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\devanagarinumeral{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\small{\devanagarinumeral{section}.\devanagarinumeral{subsection}}}   
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Large \devanagarinumeral{page}}
\section[\texorpdfstring{\Large प्रथमोऽध्यायः}{Chapter 1}]{प्रथमोऽध्यायः}
\subsection[\texorpdfstring{\Large प्रथमः पादः}{Part 1}]{प्रथमः पादः}
\begin{english}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `\Large` in

```
\section[\texorpdfstring{\Large प्रथमोऽध्यायः}{Chapter 1}]{प्रथमोऽध्यायः}
```

The optional argument is used for running headings. If you remove `\Large`, the problem is solved. Similarly in

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\small{\devanagarinumeral{section}.\devanagarinumeral{subsection}}}   
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Large \devanagarinumeral{page}}
```

the `\small` and `\Large` are unnecessary.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
   \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{{अमुकग्रन्थे}}
\rhead{{\normalsize\rightmark}}
\cfoot{{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\devanagarinumeral{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\devanagarinumeral{section}.\devanagarinumeral{subsection}}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\devanagarinumeral{page}}
\section[\texorpdfstring{प्रथमोऽध्यायः}{Chapter 1}]{प्रथमोऽध्यायः}
\subsection[\texorpdfstring{\Large प्रथमः पादः}{Part 1}]{प्रथमः पादः}
\begin{english}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Harish! That worked. I might have mixed up the optional and mandatory section command arguments.